# VSCode imports are not working as they used to after switching from Js to Ts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I was using javascript for Create-React-App, and currently switched to typescript. After creating a new react app, the auto-imports that worked when I was using javascript suddenly stopped working.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { useState } from "react";
```

(these auto imports don't show up)

How can I solve this problem?

I tried restarting VScode several times, and sometimes the auto-imports worked, but sometimes they didn't.

Comment: What do you mean by `auto imports`? Do you mean the vscode feature where when you use something from a lib it adds the import to the top automatically?

Comment: What does your tsconfig.json look like ?

Comment: Yes, the auto imports that I mentioned means the VSCode features which adds the import to the top automatically.

Comment: `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
`

Comment: This is my tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is what the issue was, my include was limiting what the TS compiler was looking at in my project, I commented it out and it started working.

You can either comment it out or include JS files as well.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["./services/*"]
    }
  },
  // "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"], // <- comment this out
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this problem. Here are some things you can try:

1. Make sure your file has the correct extension (.ts or .tsx) and that you are working in a TypeScript project.
2. Make sure you have the latest version of the "typescript" package installed in your project.
3. Make sure you have the "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" extension installed in VSCode.
4. Make sure you have the "ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets" extension installed in VSCode.
5. Make sure you've set up your TypeScript project correctly by including a tsconfig.json file.
6. Try clearing the VSCode cache and restarting the editor.
7. If the problem persists, you can try creating a new project and importing your files into it.